# XServer: active xserver sessions in background

Tags: linux, x11, xorg, x-server

I need to run some-program which makes screen capturing via xlib library in separate xserver session. So, I start my ubuntu 14 and `origin` xserver session (lets call it this way) started and after that I run

```
startx some-program
```

After running this command a black screen appears and on this black screen I see my program and it works as expected. That's ok - this is what I need.

However, firstly I want to use my computer and secondly I must run N such programs in N separate xserver sessions. The problem is that when I try to return to my `origin` session by pressing ctrl+alt+f7 some-program continues working however, its screen captures become simple black rectangles (no any content).

How can I start my some-program in separate xserver session and leave it running as I am still using that session?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the answer in xorg mailing list:

> Using it this way is nearly impossible: for some historical reasons,
>   inactive server stops drawing. Well, not just historical: it is a
>   reasinable approach to stop wasting resources to draw unseen things.
>
> However, you can start virtual X server (like standard Xvfb),and draw
>   on it just fine.
>
> You can even try to work interactively with programs on that server
>   via something like x2x or x11vnc or x2godesktopsharing, however,
>   usually interactive experience is worse than with console server.
>
> Also, no hardware 3D acceleration will be available. It also works
>   only on active console currently. If you need it, you can try to use
>   some server-in-window servers like xpra, however, it is not perfect
>   (and all attempts to implement it in the past -- Xgl, AIGLX was not
>   perfect also).